# Mongoose Performance issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm staring having issue with mongoose at high concurrency,

in this case:

**mock.js**  send a lot (10K per sec) data via socket.io to the server

**server.js** receive and process them, call **db.js** to save it (async)

**db.js** storage processed data to mongodb via mongoose (insert only)

first, I started the server, and try to do some load test by **mock.js**,

Normally, mongoose will create hundreds of connections to mongodb, with about 9K insert operations.

However, the situation I met was:

Mongodb will not react during the load test. It only has dozens of inserts and about 10 connections.

After the load test is canceled (stop sending data), the number of inserts and connections of mongodb will soar instantly until the execution is completed.

If the load test is not canceled, mongodb will not be loaded until **server.js** meets OOM

Comment: Load/performance questions are highly dependant on code, hardware and test setup.  It's nearly impossible to provide any input unless you define all those clearly and completely.

Comment: sure, this is github link: https://github.com/older-fox/bilibiliDanmuBot

Comment: ***test.js*** to run it,
***mock.js*** load tester